# Ubuntu 19.10 presents no login screen

Tags: boot, login-screen, 19.10

i have upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 and then 19.10. With 19.10 i don't get a login screen anymore. I'm using crypt_setup to encrypt my boot ssd. This system is a single OS installation.

System:
Lenovo Thinkpad X240

Booting procedure:

1. BIOS shows up
2. No Grub menu is showing up
3. crypt_setup prompts for the password in fancy mode (not console).
4. After entering the password Ubuntu loading dots are appearing
5. I just see a purple background - no matter if i hit any key.

I am still able to get a console with ALT+CTRL+F3, if switch back to ALT+CTRL+F1 i see a normal login screen and can login.

Comment: Go into console mode and check if update was successful. Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop gdm3`

Comment: This may also be a video driver issue. I don't know what is in a Thinkpad x240 but, if it's nvidia, you may need to reinstall them.

Comment: update was successfull, no error messages on apt install.
I just have a Intel graphicscards, no nvidia or amd.

Comment: Did you try the command I mentioned above? What did you get?

Comment: already newset version.